# How can I get the Facebook SDK version used for react-native-fbsdk module

Tags: android, facebook, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

In facebook developers page (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android) says that for Facebook SDK 4.14.0 version, Facebook Login has automatic integration with Facebook Lite, but i am working with react-native-fbsdk (https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk) module, so I want to know what version of FB SDK is used in.

Thanks.

Comment: I too am wondering this.  I have a version on an iOS app I'm working on and have no clue what SDK version I am using and need to find out so I can find out what graph version I'm using and upgrade if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS, Open Xcode and use this path Libraries -> RCTFBSDK.xcodeproj -> RCTFBSDK -> Core -> RCTFBSDKInitializer.m

OR

Do a global search in the project for "FBSDKSettings".

Add the following lines in the init method. 
This would tell you what version of Facebook SDK and Graph API you are using.

NSLog(@"Printing Facebook SDK version %@ ", [FBSDKSettings sdkVersion]);

NSLog(@"Printing Facebook graphAPIVersion %@ ",  [FBSDKSettings graphAPIVersion]);

Answer (score 0):

From your project folder,

```
cd android/.idea/libraries
ls
```

look for a file with a name like: facebook_android_sdk_4_22_0.xml

The version is in the file name.

That will tell you what is currently installed.  You can look in Android Studio to see what will be installed, if you update.

In Android Studio,

1. expand the Gradle Scripts block in the Project Explorer.
2. Look for a Gradle script called,

   build.gradle (Module: react-native-fbsdk)
3. open it.
4. One of the dependencies will be a line that looks like:

   compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+')

That line will tell you what version of the SDK Android Studio will download